# how to check if data context is set before applying DataTrigger?

Tags: wpf

In my style i have this

```
<Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
      </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

this checks the datacontext for the 'IsSelected' value,the problem is that i have datacontext set manually in code,
so i get this error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='MyWindow')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsSelected; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name='MyWindow'); target element is 'Tile' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

but when I set it the error is gone , so my question is how to check if the data context property isn't null before check the 'IsSelected' property ?

Comment: As far as I know. When you change the `DataContext` property, this should update **all** bindings on that object and it's children, so this shouldn't be too much of an issue. Otherwise, you could use a `MultiDataTrigger`.

Comment: thanks :) it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a MultiDataTrigger, so youwill able to check a number of conditions before to start the event. Here is the code to start with:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElemantName=WindowName, Path=DataContext}" Value="{x:Type YourDataContextType}" />
        <!--put here an additional condition you need-->
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="true" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
       <!--here you define things you want to be done on your trigger-->
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

**Update**
Please try to use this article as a guide for your problem:
[Triggers in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF).

**Update 2**
Use the next approach:

1. Create the [behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) that will monitor the DataContext changing (subscribe on [DataContextChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)).
2. Create [attached property](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vikie4u/attached-properties-in-wpf/) that will give you boolean indication if the control have the DataContext.
3. When the behavior will recognize the data context changing, update the attached property value.
4. Build your trigger from here...

Please let me know if will still have a problem.
I'll be glad to help if you will have problems with code.

Regards.

Comment: well , after testing this is the code ```<Condition Value="{x:Type stats:Assignment}">
                                                                            <Condition.Binding>
                                                                                <Binding diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
                                                                            </Condition.Binding>
                                                                        </Condition>``` it doesn't work

Comment: the problem is the first condition, you can't check a value by a type